# Forecasting assumptions

Tags: forecasting

When making forecasts, we make a few assumptions. One is that the model we estimated is the true model. Another is that the forecasts have the same distribution determined by the variance of the residuals.

Are these correct, and if so what is the point (with simple GARCH models for example) of assuming the model to be a true fit do? The model is fairly naive, so surely skepticism is almost mandatory.

What other assumptions do we make, not including those that underly the estimation of the model?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

> One is that the model we estimated is the true model.

This assumption is not correct. Several types of time series (for example those from retail demand) don't correspond to a single data generating process, so there is no "true model" - there is at best a combined effect of multiple processes, so the model we use is chosen because it gives the best forecasts, not because it corresponds to a true model.

See for example [this discussion](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crossvalidation/):

> Many statisticians like to use BIC because it is consistent — if there is a true underlying model, then with enough data the BIC will select that model. However, in reality there is rarely if ever a true underlying model, and even if there was a true underlying model, selecting that model will not necessarily give the best forecasts (because the parameter estimates may not be accurate).

Comment: by true, I mean that we assume the model is true so that the variables that affect the dependent are assumed to continue affecting it in a similar manner to the model that is generated. Otherwise, there would be no point to modelling the series of the dependent variable.